# Finding Thévenin resistance in a circuit with dependent sources which depend on a different loop

Tags: thevenin

I have this circuit:

[image]

I want to find Thévenin's resistance for this. From what I was taught, the way to do this (since there is a dependent source) is to connect a 1 V source across terminal ab, short all independent sources, find the current across ab, then find R_th using Ohm's law.

Di I have to short the independent sources on the left side loop as well? Because as I understood it, R_th is the net resistance contribution across terminal ab and there is no resistance contribution due to the left side loop. Shorting or not shorting it affects the value of I_0 which will change the answer.

Comment: First determine current \$i_o\$ whose value depends on \$V_x\$ which is actually \$V_{th}\$ you want. I find -1 V for \$V_{th}\$. Then, set the 3-V source to 0 V and install a current generator \$I_T\$ across the output. Determine the voltage \$V_T\$ across its terminal, then \$R_{th}=\frac{V_T}{I_T}\$ and I found 8.33 ohms. This output resistance is the small-signal output resistance of this circuit. It is confirmed by SPICE with a .TF statement.

Answer (score 0):

ALL independent sources are set to zero.

Comment: What if there is no wire connecting the 2 loops? What to do then?

Comment: Doesn't matter. The fact that what happens in one loop depends on what happens in the other means that there is a sort of "connection." Indeed, such a circuit might arise when there is some sort of active device involved that provides the communication.      And- it is desirable to understand and be able to use the test source method.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the whole problem. Set no sources to zero.

Calculate the Thevenin equivalent voltage Vt. It's the same as Vx when there's no load. The calculation needs a pair of equations. Eliminate current Io and solve Vx.

Then short the output. Calculate the short circuit current Is. The Thevenin equivalent resistance is Vt/Is.